# Image loads in the incorrect position, but corrects itself upon a window resize

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm working on a login page and have a container that holds left- and right-containers. The left just has a label, where the one on the right has a login form and logo in a vbox.

The issue is that when the page loads the image is offset to the right from the center of its container, despite the pack and align being set to 'center'. If I resize the window even a pixel the position corrects itself, so I'm trying to figure out how to prevent that.

I added a transform to the container's class, and it would fix it on load, but as soon as I resized the window it would offset the image in the opposite direction. I've also tried absolute positioning the element with the top and left set to 0 and it didn't change the position at all.

I stepped through the code a bit and got into an animation handler of some sort that actually resulted in the image repositioning, unfortunately I don't have any more detailed information about where that was or what process it was going through.

The CSS around the component is pretty basic, and there aren't that many configs for them, either, so if anyone has any ideas as to why this may be happening I would appreciate it.

```
{
  xtype: 'container',
  reference: 'formPanel',
  height: '100%',
  width: '42%',
  layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'center',
    pack: 'center'
  },

  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'image',
      cls: 'companyLogo',
      bind: {
        src: '{logo}'
      }
    },
    {
      xtype: 'login-form' //contains the uses of the login classes
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
.companyLogo{
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.loginButton{
  height: 50px;
}
.loginPanel{
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 270px;
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that it only happens when I'm using a vbox layout, although the other layouts present their own issues.

I tracked down when the shift occurs, and it's within Ext.Function definition. When fireHandlers runs it gets to an if statement that triggers the actual movement of the component.

Answer (score 0):

You could try call a resize event to see if that fixes it.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Comment: I tried that in a couple of different ways but couldn't get it to work the way I expected. I set up a listener for an afterrender event (also an afterlayout event with no change in behavior) that would then force a window resize, which it would, but all that took place before the image's container had been loaded into the page.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate, then your best bet would be to actually track down the root of the problem and find out where the translation animation is occurring.  Check in all your script files.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Sencha, I added an explicit width value in the CSS for the image and it was able to position itself properly. It doesn't fix the issue for when that image has to change to something else, but the lesson is that an image has to provide both a height AND width value to its container.